# Using rspec, device and sentient_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec2

I am using Devise with sentient_user Gem - https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user. 
It works fine when I user the current_user in the model. 
The Problem is that my Rspec test are failing . 
In My Rspec test I have

```
  describe MyModelWhereIUseCurrentUser do

    include Devise::TestHelpers

    before(:each) do 
      @user = Factory(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end 

   describe "current_user should work here" do 
     it "should do something" do 
       # Reference to MyModelWhereIUseCurrentUser and current_user is null there
     end
   end 
 end
```

Then in the describe block I called the model where I use
current user. 
My Test Fails because current_user is nil. 
Did I not sign in the user correctly or the problem is in the sentient_user ?

Answer (score 2):

sentient_user adds a `make_current` method, which can be called on User instance. Your problem can be fixed by adding `@user.make_current` to before block.